# Initializing multiple variables from same source in one line (JAVA)

Tags: java, coding-style, code-cleanup

Given the method:

```
private Object[] method(){
    //run some codes
    return new Object[]{Obj1, Obj2};
}
```

Note that 2 different runs will give unique outputs therefore the following will be incorrect

```
Object obj1run1 = method()[0], obj2run1 = method()[1];
//Because the method will be run 2 times with 2 unique results;
```

I know i can solve my issues by doing:

```
Object hold[] = method();
obj1run1 = hold[0];
obj2run1 = hold[1];
```

But I am looking for a minimal and quick way of writing the code, like say:

```
(obj1run1, obj2run1) = method();
//saw this somewhere but doesnt work on Java
```

So my question (using the above example): **How do i assign contents of an array into multiple variables in as little lines of codes as possible?**

Comment: Java doesn't support this kind of unpacking.

Comment: That can be done in some languages, but java does not support it.

Comment: @khelwood is there an alternative? or is my subscribed solution the only one?

Comment: There are alternatives but none of them really do what you're asking for. You could pass mutable arguments _into_ the method and mutate them, instead of getting objects returned out. You could put the "return" values into member variables instead of returning them. You could return some instance of a class that holds all the various things you wanted to return. But nothing as elegant as `x,y = method()`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> (obj1run1, obj2run1) = method();
> ```

This syntax, commonly referred as *reading a tuple*, is available in several other languages (Swift, latest C#, etc.) [but not in Java](https://dzone.com/articles/whats-wrong-java-8-part-v).

Although your solution works fine, you may be better off creating a special class for returning your particular tuple. Since the two objects that you return are related in *some* way, at least by virtue of being returned from the same method, it may be a good idea to define a class for them:

```
class HoldingPair {
    private final Object first;
    private final Object second;
    public Object getFirst() { return first; }
    public Object getSecond() { return second; }
    public HoldingPair(Object a, Object b) {
        first = a;
        second = b;
    }
    ... // hashCode, equal, toString
}
```

Now your method could return a `HoldingPair` object, which you would be able to use directly, for example

```
HoldingPair hold = method();
...
if (hold.getFirst() != null) {
    ...
}
if (hold.getSecond() != null) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mix both of your solutions but you can't do multiple affectation like in python or scala. Depending of the context, you can always find something pretty to do it. The minimal way to do it is:

```
Object hold[] = method();
Object obj1run1 = hold[0], obj2run1 = hold[1];
```

But you can create your own Tuple if semantically, there is a strong link between those two Objects.